# How close to 5 kHz can I set the PWM frequency on an UNO pin 11?

Tags: pwm

I'm rebuilding a laser CNC machine and using [LaserWeb4](https://github.com/LaserWeb/LaserWeb4/wiki) as the control interface and [GRBL 1.1](https://github.com/gnea/grbl/wiki/Connecting-Grbl) as the low-level interface to the stepper motors, limit switches and the laser. I have all the motion sorted out and am working on the laser control.

[image]

*Figure 1. The GRBL 1.1 pinout. Pin 11 is used for spindle (cutter) speed on a milling machine or laser power control on a laser cutter.*

The machine is using a [Synrad 48 Series](https://www.synrad.com/sites/default/files/2017-07/Operators%20Manual%2048%20Series.pdf) laser module which requires a 5 kHz PWM frequency (page 45 - 46).

The GRBL 1.1 sketch can be configured for a variety of PWM frequencies. See [cpu_map.h](https://github.com/gnea/grbl/blob/master/grbl/cpu_map.h).

```
  // Prescaled, 8-bit Fast PWM mode.
  #define SPINDLE_TCCRA_INIT_MASK   ((1<<WGM20) | (1<<WGM21))  // Configures fast PWM mode.
  // #define SPINDLE_TCCRB_INIT_MASK   (1<<CS20)               // Disable prescaler -> 62.5kHz
  // #define SPINDLE_TCCRB_INIT_MASK   (1<<CS21)               // 1/8 prescaler -> 7.8kHz (Used in v0.9)
  // #define SPINDLE_TCCRB_INIT_MASK   ((1<<CS21) | (1<<CS20)) // 1/32 prescaler -> 1.96kHz
  #define SPINDLE_TCCRB_INIT_MASK      (1<<CS22)               // 1/64 prescaler -> 0.98kHz (J-tech laser)

  // NOTE: On the 328p, these must be the same as the SPINDLE_ENABLE settings.
  #define SPINDLE_PWM_DDR     DDRB
  #define SPINDLE_PWM_PORT  PORTB
  #define SPINDLE_PWM_BIT     3    // Uno Digital Pin 11
```

It seems that my options are 62.5 kHz, 7.8 kHz, 1.96 kHz or 0.98 kHz.

Why does it matter? Two excerpts from the Synrad manual:

> Tickle frequencies [a 'keep-awake' signal at zero power] lower than 4.5 kHz may compromise laser performance, ..., and stress the RF [radio frequency] electronics thereby reducing long term reliability while tickle frequencies greater than 5 kHz may cause unintended lasing.
>
> Because laser output follows PWM input with a rise and fall time constant of ~100 µs, the laser cannot precisely follow Command signal frequencies over t kHz with duty cycles greater than 50%.

Can anyone see a workaround for this within the constraints of the GRBL configuration?

I can only think of a hardware solution to filter the PWM out and run it through another device to convert the analog signal to a 5 kHz PWM.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing and the answer to your question could save me a lot of time. Did you have to filter the PWM out and run it through another uno to convert the analog signal to a 5 kHz PWM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot have hardware PWM at 5 kHz on pin 11 of an Arduino
Uno. The closest you can get is 3.92 kHz. You get that by setting
the prescaler to 8 and configuring the timer for phase correct PWM,
instead of the fast PWM mode usually used by GRBL. Your options for
getting 5 kHz are to use either software PWM or change the pinout.

You can get a quite accurate 5 kHz PWM signal on pins 3, 9
and 10. You can do software PWM at 5 kHz on any pin, but this
is prone to have significant jitter, which your laser may well not like.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way, which may interfere with the timing of your other digital outputs:  https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PwmFrequency

Or, if you are willing to put the PWM output on pin 9/10 and manipulate the AVR registers directly:

Digital pins 9 (`OC1A`) and 10 (`OC1B`) are outputs of the AVR 16-bit timer (TIMER1) on 328p.  With those you can get a PWM signal at 5.000 kHz, but if you need reliability then an Arduino with external crystal resonator may be needed.   You will need to set the registers `TCCR1A`, `TCCR1B` and `OCR1A`,`OCR1B`,`ICR1`,`TIFR1` appropriately, details can be found in the AVR datasheet.

Comment: The ceramic resonator of the Uno is reliable, if neither accurate nor stable.